# How to fix error with multiple upload with Symfony 4 NoSuchPropertyException

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I want to add a field for upload many attached files in a form with Symfony 4. I've two Entity, Member and Documents with a One-To-Many relation but I've an error who doesn't mean anything for me.

In my Entity Document I've this :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Member", inversedBy="document")
     */
    private $member;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $file
     */
    public function setFile($file): void
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getMember(): ?Member
    {
        return $this->member;
    }

    public function setMember(?Member $member): self
    {
        $this->member = $member;

        return $this;
    }
```

In my Member Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MemberRepository")
 */
class Member
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Documents", mappedBy="member", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $document;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->years = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->document = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->atelier = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Documents[]
     */
    public function getDocument(): Collection
    {
        return $this->document;
    }


    public function addDocument(Documents $document): self
    {
        if (!$this->document->contains($document)) {
            $this->document[] = $document;
            $document->setMember($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDocument(Documents $document): self
    {
        if ($this->document->contains($document)) {
            $this->document->removeElement($document);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($document->getMember() === $this) {
                $document->setMember(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I've try to dump the value of my form but when I try to send my form, I've this error when I don't understand

```
Could not determine access type for property "document" in class "App\Entity\Member": The property "document" in class "App\Entity\Member" can be defined with the methods "addDocument()", "removeDocument()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Documents" given.
```

Comment: Are you sure `self` type hint can be used in that context?

Comment: It seems your entity expect a Collection of documents. What are you posting right now ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux I'm trying to send a form. Everything's work except the upload. With the upload, I'm trying to send any file, like an image or a pdf...

Comment: @ReynierPM The self appeared when I've made the relation between my entities...